# Error while saving PDF file in SAP GUI Loadrunner

Tags: user-interface, loadrunner, sap-gui

I need to record a SAP GUI Loadrunner script to save a PDF file.

It's working fine until I preview the file. But when I use the tcode PDF! To do a save as in my system it's displaying

> Acrobat reader failed. Close the program.

Comment: @james pulley I  am creating test data for performance testing a sales force application. I need to upload this PDF file generated in sap GUI as part of the scenario. Manually downloading 1000+ files is a tedious job. Hence I am looking for a solution to automate the process to reduce test data creation time. Kindly suggest any approach.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you plan on turning your local file system into a bottleneck for your entire performance test by saving PDF files from tens/hundreds of users to the local disk?   This appears to be a carry over from some sort of functional test

Comment: Is this possible with any other tools?  We are running out of time. Any suggestions will be of great help

Comment: Have you considered a GUI virtual user.  The resource requirements for Acrobat are so high that I would not expect it to run en masse.  Also, saving files to your load generators during a test would pretty much turn the local file system into a bottleneck for the entire test

Comment: Hi James, could you please elaborate on GUI virtual test. I am planning to run a single user test with sufficient think time just to save PDF files for test data creation.

Comment: GUI Virtual User.  Covered in Training and in the manual.  This is QTP driving your full front end application

Comment: I tried recording using uft..the save command is not captured there also... please provide more details